# String was not recognized as a valid DateTime in ParseExact with Milliseconds

Tags: c#, datetime

I have a Date in string format, I need to convert it in DateTime, this is my code:

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact("2018-04-09T09:27:07.247+02:00", "YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.SSSZ", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToUniversalTime();
Console.WriteLine(TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(dt, TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("W. Europe Standard Time")).ToString());
```

It works with date like: 2020-08-27T00:00:00+02:00, but it doesn't work with a date like the one in the script because of millis. How should I change the date pattern? I've tried many of them, but I didn't solve.

Comment: I don't think it works for `2017-03-01T00:00:00+01:00`.

Comment: @John I was watchin your answer and you deleted it, why? it seems working

Comment: I realised that `DateTime` ignores the timezone and I was triple checking that `DateTimeOffset` handles it correctly. It's generally best not to leave incorrect answers hanging around if it will take more than a moment to correct, lest I attract downvotes :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are three problems with your code:

1. Format strings are case sensitive (yyyy represents a 4-digit year, YYYY does not, likewise dd represents a 2-digit day, whereas DD does not).
2. `.sss` should be `.fff` for milliseconds.
3. You're expecting Z (Zulu) but you're actually getting a time offset ("+02:00"). This means that the format string differs from your datetime string.

I suggest you don't bother with `DateTime.ParseExact` for ISO8601 datetimes, just use `DateTimeOffset`'s `Parse` instead (which will obey the time offset and work with ISO8601 datetimes):

```
DateTimeOffset dt = DateTimeOffset.Parse("2018-04-09T09:27:07.247+02:00", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToUniversalTime();
Console.WriteLine(TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(dt.DateTime, TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("W. Europe Standard Time")).ToString());
```

Comment: Also the `.SSS` is not valid.  That should be `.fff` for milliseconds.

Comment: @juharr Thank you! I completely missed that.