# DateTime.ParseExact Failing to convert to correct date

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, datetime, fullcalendar

I am using [FullCalendar](https://fullcalendar.io/). Now there is a code where I get a Date/Time from FullCalendar API. This is called `startDate` and has a below format:

> String. An ISO8601 string representation of the start date. It will
> have a timezone offset similar to the calendar’s timeZone e.g.
> 2018-09-01T12:30:00-05:00. If selecting all-day cells, it won’t have a
> time nor timezone part e.g. 2018-09-01.

Let us for this question, assume that `startStr` is `2020-11-15T23:00:00-08:00`

I have an ASP.NET MVC backend, where I send this string using Javascript.
The server receives the correct string as above i.e. `2020-11-15T23:00:00-08:00`
Now, there is a code where I parse this date to the `DateTime` object

```
DateTime sdt = DateTime.ParseExact(sstartStr, "yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'sszzz", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

But here, this date/time is parsed as `11/16/2020 12:30:00 PM`.
(You can try parsing the said date using the above code, the output will be wrong as above.)

**Am I missing something ?**

Comment: It's adjusting it to your timezone.  When I parse it I get 2AM

Comment: @juharr Yes, but how to correct it ?

Comment: It's not incorrect. You need to format the value of `sdt` to the time zone you wish it to be in (presumably UTC).

Comment: @HereticMonkey I wish it to be in the timezone which was in the incoming string i.e. `-08:00` in this case. How to do that ?

Comment: `DateTime` does not include timezone information.  For that you'd need a `DateTimeOffset`.  Check out this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/64969806/302918